# Run spring boot app on Jboss Wildfly server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, wildfly

I would like to build a Spring Boot application and run it on a JBOSS Wildfly server hosted in our infrastructure. It's a Spring MVC application , but I would like to use Spring Boot as it is easy to bootstrap the app. Is it sufficient if I follow the steps listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25245834/spring-boot-without-embedded-servlet-container)?

Comment: This might help. https://spring.io/blog/2014/03/07/deploying-spring-boot-applications#what-about-the-java-ee-application-server

Comment: Thanks @Rjiuk. This helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short, the two required steps are to extend the `org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer` in your Spring Boot application and exclude the embedded `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` in the `pom.xml`.

Here is an updated tutorial which works with WildFly 20 and *Spring Boot 2.3.3*:
[Spring Boot Hello World on WildFly](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-frameworks/spring/spring-boot-hello-world-on-wildfly)